# is it possible to get jdbc configuration variables in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have multiple JDBC Configurations set for different DBs in JMeter. Now i would like to use one of the configurations in a BeanShell to fetch some data programatically.

Is it possible to fetch JDBC Configuration parameters like 'Database URL', 'JDBC Driver class', 'Username', 'Password' using 'Variable Name' set in the JDBC Configuration element?
[image: JDBC Configuration element]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, check out [DatabaseMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/.html) class

Example code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jdbc.config.DataSourceElement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;

Connection conn = DataSourceElement.getConnection("ABC");

DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();

log.info("URL: " + meta.getURL());
log.info("Driver class: " + meta.getDriverVersion());
log.info("Username: " + meta.getUserName());
//etc.
```

I don't have Oracle to play with, but I believe it'll work there as well:

[image: JDBC from Beanshell]

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) article for more information on using JMeter and Java APIs from Beanshell test elements.

Comment: Thanks alot. This is useful to me. I will try and use it now